# Is there a way to automate POI collection from websites?

Tags: qgis, data

I am searching for an easy method to get lots of points geotagged/georeferenzed into several shape files.

I am working at a project where I need to collect all parcel shops in germany (but I will try it with Berlin first) of the 5 most important service providers. 
They are all not willing to give me any data of their locations but they all have a web formular to search the shops in a specific region.

I like to create 1 shape file for each company with all their shops in Berlin.

Do you have another idea how to do that while avoiding to search and add every single point (or just using google maps and tag/screenshot the points)?

To have an impression of the material I use: [image: UPS Parcel shop localiser]

The points you can see on the map (and on the left side with some explanation) need to be transferred into QuantumGis.